# How can I link to a page with the same title in a different dir?

Tags: javascript, html, web, redirect, directory

I currently have file system that looks like this:

```
example.com/project/EN/1/2/2.html
example.com/project/DE/1/2/2.html
```

All websites have the same base html file, and I would like to add a button where users can switch between different languages but stay on the same page (`/1/2/2.html`).

The button would therefore need to be able to get the current location and create the other links (to `/DE/`, `/FR/`, etc) on the spot.

I tried to get the current url and then produce the other urls respectively, but failed because I couldn’t figure out how to fetch only parts of the url.

Comment: You have to get this started with Javascript. You need to parse the URL and replace the language-part.

Comment: That should be in the button's click handler: `let s_old = window.location.href; window.location.href  = s_old.replace(/\/[A-Z]{2}\/, "/DE/");`. The second argument to `replace` contains the target language code.